# ICSP, Debugging, UART and SPI on same pins, dsPIC30F4011

Tags: pic, serial

In my project I plan to use SPI1 module of the dsPIC30F4011 ([datasheet pdf](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/70135C.pdf)) micro-controller.
The pin-out makes pins 1 and 44 both PGC/PGD and serial COM pins for UART1 and also SPI1 modules. I can live with using UART2 module (which uses other pins), but there is only one SPI module on the device and I would like to debug the device as well. **Is it possible to use the SPI module and debug?** Doesn't seem like it.

Also, for programming the device I should isolate PGC/PGD when my PicKit3 is connected from application SPI devices. I don't think I can use simple resistors, because they would have to be high valued ([10k minimum seems to be required](https://www.kanda.com/pic_programmer_icsp_guide.php)) and SPI might not work properly. Can anyone confirm this? So my options are to do some switching with transistors or to use jumpers.

Comment: You can apparently debug using one of the EMUxx pin pairs, but you still need PGC/PGD to program the device. So presumably once you've programmed, you disconnect, switch from PCG/PGD to EMUCx/EMUDx, and reconnect. Some other PICs have multiple PGC/PGD pin pair options, but I guess this one is old enough that this idea hadn't been fully developed yet.

Comment: That seems like something to investigate. Thank you. Whould you have any advice on pin isolation for SPI?